# How to prove that : $ d.e = \displaystyle \sum_{ p \in C \cap D } \mathrm{dim} \ \mathcal{O}_{ \mathbb{P}^{2} } / (f,g) $?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $ C \subset \mathbb{P}^2 $ be a smooth curve defined by a homogeneous polynomial $ f $ of degree $ d $.

Let $ D \subset \mathbb{P}^2 $ be a second smooth curve defined by a homogeneous polynomial $ g $ of degree $ e $.

How to show that :
$$ d ~ .e = \displaystyle \sum_{ p \in C \cap D } \mathrm{dim} \ \mathcal{O}_{ \mathbb{P}^{2} } / (f,g) $$

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: This is known as Bezout's theorem. Why don't you look up a proof in some standard book (like Fulton).  For smooth curves, there are other proofs, but it is good to know a proof of Bezout's theorem.

Comment: Fulton's book doesn't provide a proof of this theorem. Fulton only introduce this notion by a family of axioms.

Comment: Section 5.3 of [Fulton](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf).